# Can't seem to get jQuery to go global with Electron / Webpack

Tags: webpack

I'm setting up a new Electron app and just trying to build the scaffolding for it.

I've used webpack / bootstrap / jquery before together and have never had an issue so I don't understand why but for the life of me I keep getting

`Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.`

I've tried this in my `webpack.config.js` file
With / Without the `resolve` and multiple other file locations

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        jquery: "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    }
  }, 
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
    })
  ],
```

if I look at my `bundle.js` I can clearly see `jQuery` being loaded but for some reason Bootstrap keeps barking at me

Using `Bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6` and `jquery` npm installs

Anybody got any suggestions on why it can't seem to find `jQuery`

If I open developer tools I can definitely see `$` is a global variable, however `jQuery` is not and that seems to be what bootstrap checks against. Thanks.

Entire Webpack

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  debug: true,
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/public/javascripts/main.js'
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
        jquery: "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
    }
  }, 
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
            sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
          }
        }
      },
      { test: /bootstrap\/js\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          plugins: ['transform-flow-strip-types']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /tether\.js$/,
        loader: "expose?Tether"
      },
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/,  loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
      { test: /\.eot$/,    loader: "file-loader" },
      { test: /\.svg$/,    loader: "file-loader" }
    ]
  }
}
```

And in my `main.js`

```
import jQuery from "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import BootstrapCSS from "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import BootstrapJS from "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
```

Ok this appears to be related to my `gulp` setup I guess, if I run my gulp webpack which does

```
gulp.task("webpack", () => {
  return gulp.src("./dist/public/javascripts/main.js")
  .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/public/javascripts/"));
});
```

It seems to not work, but if I manually run `webpack` and drag and drop the bundle, it works just fine. Any suggestions?